# Filtering two Data Extensions against each other

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, data, filters

I'm trying to create a filtered Data Extension where the source Data Extension filters out records using corresponding records in another Data Extension.

Does anyone have any idea on how to do this? I might be completely on the wrong track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively, you can write queries using SQL, from Email Studio -> Interactions -> Query. This is often an easier approach to filtering data extensions where more than one DE is involved in the filter.

You can then make use of INNER JOIN and EXISTS clauses.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to create a Data Relationship, linking the two DE's to each other and then you can create a filtered data extension based on records in another DE.

You find Data Relationship in Email Studio => Subscribers => Data Relationships :)

Comment: Thanks Kenneth!

How would you then go about filtering the Data Extension? I have read that it is possible in Data Relationships but i can;t find any help on how to exactly do it.

Comment: Hey will - is this still relevant? Thought i answered already